# How do you use atoi to assign individual elements of a char array?

Tags: c, atoi

So as we all probably know, the `atoi` converts a char to a number. But, what do you do if you only want one of the array elements instead of the whole array?

Please look at the following:

```
for (h = 0; h < 5; h++)
{
    num[h] = atoi(temp[h]);
}
```

Assume that num is an array of type `int` and that temp is and array of type `char`. This gives me one of those annoying conversion problems:

> Invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char *'

Any suggestions on how to convert a single element of a char array to an int using atoi?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you only want to convert a single character you don't need to use `atoi()`:

```
if (temp[h] >= '0' && temp[h] <= '9')
{
    num[h] = temp[h] - '0';
}
else
{
    // handle error:  character was not a digit
}
```

In C, the value of each digit is one greater than the value of the previous digit, so this is guaranteed to work.

The reason that `atoi()` does not work is because it takes a `const char*` as its argument, not a `char`.  That pointer has to point to a null terminated string.

Comment: Ok... I thought you needed to convert using atoi(). Thanks.

Comment: @kriss:  Thanks for the semicolon!  Oops!

Comment: C does not define the character encoding, so this is not "guaranteed to work".  You are assuming the character encoding is ASCII (or has the desired property), which is perhaps a reasonable assumption but it's important to know it's a assumption, not a guarantee.

Comment: @.yahoo.co:  "In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous" (C99 §5.2.1/3).

Comment: @James McNelis Yow, did not know that.  I am still thinking in C89.  Thanks.

Comment: @.yahoo.co:  That same sentence is in C89/90 §2.2.1.  You're welcome.

Comment: @yahoo: and this trick works for ages on non ASCII charset like EBCDIC, not just ASCII.

Comment: The first if can be written more efficiently as `if ((unsigned)temp[h]-'0'<10)`.

Answer (score 7):

Besides just using its integral value as shown by James, you could put it in a seperate buffer:

```
char buf[2] = { temp[h], '\0' };
num[h] = atoi(buf);
```