# Creating an int value from multiple char array fields in C

Tags: c

I'm working on a C program and i am struggling with it (I've been spoiled by the concept of object orientation).

What i want to do is this:

I want to put values in a char array into an int. So for example i have `char[0] == '1'` and `char[1] == '2'`. I want to put these values in an int variable so its value is 12. I have tried looking but I am not sure how to get this done.

I really am poor at explaining so please ask for more info if necessary.

Comment: your question shows the lack of personal research. there are tons of examples out there to solve this minor common problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use atoi to assign individual elements of a char array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251401/how-do-you-use-atoi-to-assign-individual-elements-of-a-char-array)

Comment: do you know the size of your char array?

Comment: int foo = (char_array[0] & 0x0f)*10 + (char_array[0] & 0x0f). Don't call your characters char

Comment: I think this will help: [atoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: `char buf[]={"12"}; int a = atoi(buf);`

Comment: `int value = 0; for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfArray; ++i) { value *= 10; value += array[i]; }`. When someone can answer your question in one sentence, you have probably not given it enough thought and are doing yourself a learning disservice.

Comment: thanks @OlegMazurov that actually helped. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

If your char array is made with characters `'1'` and `'2'`:

```
char a[2];
a[0] = '1';
a[1] = '2';
int b = (a[0]-'0')*10 + (a[1]-'0');
```

If your char array is made with numbers `1` and `2`:

```
char a[2];
a[0] = 1;
a[1] = 2;
int b = a[0] * 10 + a[1];
```

also, see: [Why does subtracting '0' in C result in the number that the char is representing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598698/why-does-subtracting-0-in-c-result-in-the-number-that-the-char-is-representing)

Comment: Thanks alot. This also worked.Quite a simple solution actually. Not sure how i didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1):

If the character array contains a string that is if it is zero-terminated then you can apply standard C function `atoi` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`.

For example

```
char s[] = "12";
int x = atoi( s );
```

If the array is not zero-terminated as

```
char s[2] = "12";
```

then you can convert its content to an integer manually.

For example

```
int x = 0;

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( s ) / sizeof( *s ); i++ )
{
    x = 10 * x + s[i] - '0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called parsing. In c this can be done with the atoi() function like this:

```
 char s[] = "12";
 int num = atoi(s);
```